# I'm writing HTML files and I want a program that adds list item markup tags to a list of words

Tags: php, python, html

What I'm hoping for is something like this:

Input:

```
a
aa
b
bb
```

Output:

```
<li>a</li>  
<li>aa</li>  
<li>b</li>  
<li>bb</li>
```

So I try it in python, right:

```
file = open('/Users/Shannon/Desktop/add_tags.txt')


while 1:
    line = file.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    else: 
        print "<li>" + line + "</li> \n"
```

And the result is a garbled mess like so:

```
</li> e sleep patterns when possibleresult in positive outcomes
```

Then I try it in php:

```
<html><body>

<?php
$fin = fopen('add_tags.txt', 'r');

while(!feof($fin))
    {
        $input_string = fgets($fin);
        $output_string = "<li>".$input_string."</li>";
        echo $output_string;
    }

?>
```

But the li tags render as bullet points, naturally. So I added backslashes to escape the brackets, but that appeared to have no effect. Then I changed "(lessthan) li (greaterthan)" to "x" just to see what happened - nothing. Still a bulleted list. I have no idea. Something tells me that switching to java won't solve my problems. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want it to print `<li></li>` or `&lt;li&gt;&lt/li&gt;`? Actual HTML or something that viewer can actually see what the tags would be?

Comment: I actually cannot believe any of both claims to be true. The python you posted won't print text outside of an `<li>...</li>` block and the PHP won't output `<li>...</li>` if you make it print `x...x`. Are you sure you are looking at the right files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the python solution in two lines:

```
for line in open('tmp.txt'):
  print '<li>' + line.rstrip() +'</li>'
```

And two comments:

1. The 'for line in...' style is much cleaner and easier (open(filename) returns a python generator, yielding one line at a time).
2. To get rid of trailing '\n' in the end of the lines, I used rstrip(). This also gets rid of extra spaces at the end of the line (which won't make any difference in the HTML, anyway).